# How to handle multipe if statements and cases that uses the same object in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, design-patterns, logic

I have a question of how to best order your code when using multiple if statements that uses the same object in their logic.

I am customizing column values in a table where depending on the columnId a different logic will be applied to extract the value for that specific column.

Given that I have three different columns namned "Column 1", "Column 2" and "Column 3" where both "Column 1" and "Column 3" use a customized object called obj in their logic whereas "Column 2" doesn't.

What is the best approach to order the if statements and where should I create my object? I've added three different cases, which one is best and why? Another better solotuion?

Thanks in advance!

```
// Case 1
public Object getColumnValue(String columndId) {
    if (columndId.equals("Column 1") || columndId.equals("Column 3")) {
        customObject obj = new customObject();
        if (columndId.equals("Column 1")) {
            // do something with the custom object
        } else if (columndId.equals("Column 3") ||) {
            // do something else with the custom object
        }
    } else if (columndId.equals("Column 2")) {
        // do something without the custom object
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

// Case 2
public Object getColumnValue(String columndId) {
    customObject obj = new customObject();
    if (columndId.equals("Column 1") {
        // do something with the custom object
    } else if (columndId.equals("Column 2")) {
        // // do something without the custom object
    } else if (columndId.equals("Column 3")) {
        /// do something with the custom object
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

// Case 3
public Object getColumnValue(String columndId) {
    if (columndId.equals("Column 1") {
        customObject obj = new customObject();
        // do something with the custom object
    } else if (columndId.equals("Column 2")) {
        // // do something without the custom object
    } else if (columndId.equals("Column 3")) {
        customObject obj = new customObject();
        /// do something with the custom object
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

// Case 4
public Object getColumnValue(String columndId) {
    switch (columnId) {
        case "Column 1":
        case "Column 3":
            customObject obj = new customObject();
            switch (columnId) {
                case "Column 1":
                    // do somethingt with custom object
                case "Column 3":
                    // do something else with custom object
            }
        case "Column 2":
            // do something without custom object
    }
}
```

Comment: have you heard of switch-case statements? Either way, this is rather a code review question

Comment: @Stultuske The Code Review site won't accept it though, the code is hypothetical and that never goes over well.

Comment: @Stultuske yes I have, so are you saying that ligning up multiple cases where the object should be used before creating it and then what? Each case is meant to deal with the object in different way. 

Like the case 4 I just added.

Comment: @MarcusNystad Avoiding if/else (or multiple if) involves reviewing the design of the class that owns the method `getColumnValue()`. The design pattern strategy can help replace multiple if.`

For case 4 you can extract the second `switch` in a private method to avoid `switch` nesting

Comment: @Cedric unfortunately I can't change the class that owns the method `getColumnValue()` since it's part of a codebase of a software that I'm not allowed to change. 

How should I think about when to create the object and how to nest similar ifs in the best way given this?

Comment: @Cedric in the real problem I have. There are about 10 cases that uses the same object e.g. and then 7 of them use the some object of another class and so on. 

This will lead to a lot of nesting. So basically is it better to group the similar ones all the way or just handle them separaretely? 

I end up evaluating a lot of "is it this column or this column" when nesting which could be avoided by handling them  separetely I guess.  

Not sure what's the best approach is...

Comment: @MarcusNystad It is necessarily the id of the column which allows to know if we must have a CustomColumn? if so, you can make a list of id that need the CustomColumn and you check if the list contains id provided in `getColumnValue`

Comment: @Cedric in this case actually all `columId` that enters `getColumnValue" will be customized. So I know beforehand that 22 columns with different names should be customzied. 

So basically I wonder whether the creation of the objects several times is worse than evaluating a lot of if statements in order to be able to just create the object once.

Comment: Each of the 22 columns has a different customization?

Comment: @Cedric adding the fact that nesting leads quickly to more or less unreadable code in my perspective.

Comment: @MarcusNystad Too many ifs often indicate a design error. To help you avoid too many ifs, we need to have all of your needs, which goes beyond Stackoverflow. Sorry Marcus :/

Comment: @Cedric correct. All 22 columns have different customization.

Comment: @Cedric I just want a thought on the general problem where you have different cases that uses the same objects. 

Should the object just be created once before any case that uses it or is it OK to create the object several times when it's needed under each if/case?

In my mind this is a general question that applies to a lot of similar situations and I think it should be possible to answer what's best in general given these options. 

Agree that the design before this step might be the problem but often you end up with having to write code where you can't change the underlying design.

Comment: @MarcusNystad When different cases uses the same processing, use `if` or `switch` is a personal choice :). I propose an approach by design pattern in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think Strategy design pattern is the best choice. Each customization has a dedicated class like that (with a better name that MyCustomizationStrategy):

```
public abstract class CustomizationStrategy {

  protected abstract String getSupportedColumnId(); 

  public boolean isApplicable(String columnId) {
    return getSupportedColumnId().equals(columnId);
  }

  public abstract Object customizeColumnValue(String columnId);

}

public class MyCustomizationStrategy extends CustomizationStrategy {
  private final static String SUPPORTED_COLUMN_ID = "Column X";

  @Override
  protected List<String> getSupportedColumnId() {
    return SUPPORTED_COLUMN_ID;
  }

  public Object customizeColumnValue(String columnId) {
    return ...
  }
}
```

In the class that owns `getColumnValue()`:

```
private static final List<CustomizationStrategy> CUSTOMIZATION_STRATEGIES = 
  Arrays.asList(new MyCustomizationStrategy(), ...);

public Object getColumnValue(String columndId) {
  return CUSTOMIZATION_STRATEGIES.stream()
    .filter(strategy -> strategy.isApplicable(columnId))
    .map(strategy -> strategy.customizeColumnValue(columnId))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
}
```